# Does Vietnam store visas digitally?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, vietnam, visa-expiration

I leave Vietnam next weekend, on the day my visa extension runs out. The date is a little smudged (it does read but I am concerned they'll think it's for a later date).

Is my expiry date in the immigration system? When they scan my passport, will it tell them that the visa runs out on a certain date?

Comment: What about the entry date? Is that stamped? If you got say, a 90 day visa, they can do the maths if it becomes an argument.

Answer (score 3):

I've travelled to Vietnam many times with a business visa. I am certain they keep a record of your visa on their system in correlation to your passport number.

Prior to your departure to Vietnam you should have received a visa approval letter (sample below) stating that your Visa is waiting for you at your port of arrival. This document has your DOB Full, name, Passport number and nationality. The form is electronic and thereby would be entered in a database of some sort where immigration and visa officers can cross check.

When you pass passport control, the officer will scan your passport, check your visa and cross check it with the monitor in front of them.

---

This is a sample letter:

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with a visa *extension*? These letters (I got one quite similar) entitle you to get your visa on arrival, not an extension.